# ソースからビルドしたPython3.6で、SQLite3を使用したい

Tags: python, centos, sqlite

**エラーメッセージ**

```
No module named '_sqlite3'
```

#### 試したこと

find コマンドで探してみましたが、異なる場所にあるため使用不可？

```
$ sudo find /usr/local -name _sqlite3.so**
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
```

以下のページを見てコピペしたのですが、うまくいきません。

[No module named _sqlite3 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25339281/5083443)

```
$ sudo yum install sqlite-devel
    
パッケージ sqlite-devel-3.6.20-1.el6_7.2.x86_64 はインストール済みか最新バージョンです
```

```
$ pip3.6 install pysqlite

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
/tmp/pip-build-jqf6m0fv/pysqlite/
```

**環境**
CentOS 6

```
$ which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonのビルドをしたときに、関連ライブラリがインストールされていないためにビルドされなかったモジュールの一覧、というのが表示されます。そこに `_sqlite3` も含まれていると思います。

Pythonをビルドする前にsqlite-devel をインストールして、それからPythonをビルドすればよいはずです。ビルド後に sqlite-devel をインストールしてもだめなので、 sqlite-devel を後からインストールした場合はPythonをビルドし直してください。 `make clean` してから `make` しなおす感じです。